# How to solve Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails in Spring

Tags: mysql, spring

I am using Spring and MySql database. I am trying to delete user from users table which is connected to post table as one to many relationship.

**User.java**

```
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",  fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST })
    private List<Post> posts;

        //getters and setters

    }
```

**Post.java**

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn (name="profesor_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)
private User user;

    //getters and setters
```

Profesor.java

```
@Entity
public class Profesor extends User {

    private String jobTitle;

    public String getJobTitle() {
        return jobTitle;
    }

    public void setJobTitle(String jobTitle) {
        this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
    }
}
```

**Controller.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value="profesorList/{id}/deleteProfesor", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView deleteProfesor(@PathVariable long id){
        profesorRepository.delete(id);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/profesorList");
    }
```

**index.html**

```
<td><a th:href="@{'/profesorList/{id}/deleteProfesor'(id=${profesor.id})}"</a></td>
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>, UserDetailsService {

     public User findUserByUsername(String username);

}
```

**ProfesorRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface ProfesorRepository extends JpaRepository<Profesor, Long>{

}
```

I am using one table inheritance. So I have user and profesor in same table as users.

But when I try to execute it I am getting this error:

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`data`.`post`, CONSTRAINT `FK5q2menkhkd7av4xfslbgbuq3y` FOREIGN KEY (`profesor_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`))
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a bidirectional relation, so if you are planning to remove an entity you need to remove the relation (otherwise you need to cascade your delete) so if you want to remove a Post, you need to get the user and remove this post from the post list in that user before deleting the post

Add "CascadeType.REMOVE"  in the User model as given below.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",  fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE })
private List<Post> posts;

    //getters and setters

}
```

To delete the user table entry, first have to delete the child table 'post' entry for this record.

```
@RequestMapping(value="profesorList/{id}/deleteProfesor", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView deleteProfesor(@PathVariable long id){
    Profesor  profesor = profesorRepository.findOne(id);
    if(Objects.nonNull(profesor)){
        List<Post> posts = profesor.getPosts();
        for (Iterator<Post> iterator = posts.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Post post = iterator.next();
            post.setUser(null)
            iterator.remove(); //remove the child first
        }
        profesorRepository.delete(profesor);
    }


    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/profesorList");
}
```